# What kind of action is selling cargo and contraband to a solid contact?

Tags: firefly

> **Solid**
>
> When you are Solid, Contacts will buy
> Cargo and Contraband from you. The
> prices offered appear on the Contact
> side of the Job Cards.

What kind of action is selling cargo and contraband to a solid contact?

(We've ruled that it's part of a Deal action, in the same way that you can buy fuel in addition to going through the Supply in a Buy action.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out we ruled correctly.

> **Deal Actions**
>
> If your Firefly is in a Contact’s Sector,
>   you may Deal with that Contact. You
>   may look at 3 and accept up to 2 Jobs
>   from their Contact Deck.
>
> If you are Solid with that Contact, you
>   may also sell Cargo and Contraband
>   to them as part of your Deal Action.
>   (see rules for Reputation on pg 15 for
>   details on getting Solid with Contacts).